# Detecting file system in C

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way to tell whether a file is in local disk or NFS in C? The code should be portable across various linux distros and shouldn't rely on system calls (e.g. stat -f).

Comment: Why don't you want to make a system call? Using stat is the typical method

Comment: @Jarek: stat is not portable.

Comment: @DanParadox: We are talking about the *system call* stat here, not a call to system() with stat in it, right? Because the *system call* stat conforms to SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001 on Linux, according to its manpage. Which is pretty portable.

Comment: @DanParadox: You are totally confusing a system call with a call to `system ()` function...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [`statfs`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/statfs.2.html) from `<sys/vfs.h>`.

> ```
> int statfs(const char *path, struct statfs *buf);
>
> struct statfs {
>     __SWORD_TYPE f_type;    /* type of file system (see below) */
> ```

Here's how to use it:

```
struct statfs s;
if (statfs("/etc", &s))
    perror("statfs");

switch (s->f_type) {
case EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC:
    break;
case EXT3_SUPER_MAGIC:
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Also:

- You are confusing "external commands" and "system calls". They are very very different things
- The stat(1) command is *very* portable among Linux distros.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there any way to use this for a specific file?

Comment: @DanParadox if you look carefully, you'll see a path argument in statfs.

Comment: **Word of caution:**  don't test for etx2/etx3 --- my local file system on Fedora16 is BTRFS which would probably be the new default in near future -- same probelm is with XFS, and ReiserFS etc.   So instead test for file systems you want to _exclude_ such at NFS and SMB